# Update an array of 1000000 items in parallel

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, parallel-processing

This is a question which was asked in previous year exam.

> Consider the following fragment of C code:

```
int i, array[1000000];
array[0] = 0;
for (i = 1; i < 1000000; i++)
array[i] = array[i-1] + 3;
```

> Can we simply run 1,000,000 of the array update statement in the
>   for loop in parallel? If not, change the update statement so that it
>   can run in parallel and still produce the same final contents of the
>   array.

I understand that it is not possible to simply run 1,000,000 of the array update statement in the for loop in parallel. Only ways that are coming into my mind is to use recursion, which is not parallel, and to use 1000000 threads, which is not a great idea.

So is there another way of getting this done in parallel with very few update statements ? We may use openMPI or openCL

Edit: This is not a homework question, but I think it was given as homework in some school. This is from a past exam paper. I uploaded it [here](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=f302817)

Comment: On quad core or octa core the answer is no. You should consider OpenMP or CUDA programming.

Comment: Homeworks? http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~rdp/FIT5174/FIT5174-Resources-2013/FIT5174-2013-SampleTest.pdf

Comment: Yes.We may use openMPI or openCL. I will edit the question to add that.

Comment: @RicoRico; You nailed it! :D

Comment: @RicoRico not homework. Its past year exam paper. Probably my lecturer used this page to create the questions

Comment: @RicoRico 
http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=f302817
Its not homework

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot parallelize that loop, neither with only 2 thread, since each iteration depends on the previous.

Your algorithm produces:

```
array[0] = 0;
array[1] = 3;
array[2] = 6;
...
```

So, you can write the update statement in a way that each iteration does not depend on the previous:

```
int i, array[1000000];
array[0] = 0;
for (i = 1; i < 1000000; i++)
    array[i] = 3*i;
```

In this way you have removed the data dependency and you can easily parallelize the loop (e.g. with OpenMP or MPI).

Comment: Thanks. I got it now.